# Rename multiple file with no extensions?

Tags: rename

I have multiple files all named

```
seperate1
seperate2
```

etc. How do I rename them all to have the extension `.csv`?

Answer (score 1):

If there are only files which shall be renamed:

```
for file in *; do
  mv "$file" "${file}.csv"
done
```

If there are files with a dot which must be excluded:

```
for file in *; do
  [[ $file == *.* ]] && continue
  mv "$file" "${file}.csv"
done
```

Or with `shopt -s extglob`:

```
for file in +([^.]); do
  mv "$file" "${file}.csv"
done
```